# Fix Control unclickable area (when BorderStyle is Fixed3D)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**EDIT**

It seems that it's a problem with any Panel (though not every Control). Changed title accordingly. But the problem is mainly with a `SplitContainer` because there's an *internal* unclickable area.

**Original**:

In the following case, there exists an area within a SplitContainer which ignores events:

1. Create a `SplitContainer` and for safe measure set its (and its
   Panels') Padding and Margin to 0.
2. Subscribe all of them to a Click event handler.
3. I put `System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();` in that handler.
4. And now for what causes the problem: set `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D` .

Now, when clicking in most of the area, the sound is heard, but on the border between the Panels and the splitter - it isn't.

How can that be fixed (without changing the BorderStyle, of course)?

Comment: See [mouse events from a non-client area of a control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cf851eb4-52ec-4519-8d1c-eb52bc32eafd/mouse-events-from-a-nonclient-area-of-a-control?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the mouse is down in the borders from `WM_SETCURSOR` message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == 0x0020) //WM_SETCURSOR
    {
        //wParam is the window handle where the cursor is over
        if ( m.WParam == splitContainer1.Panel1.Handle || m.WParam == splitContainer1.Panel2.Handle )
        {
            if ( ((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF) == 18 ) //low 16bits of lParam -> HTBORDER
                if ( (((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16) == 0x0201) //hight 16bits -> WM_LBUTTONDOWN 
                {
                    //mouse is down
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see the `click event` then change `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` with `WM_LBUTTONUP`